# Javascript Save Max Value of Loop Variable

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, variables

I have a variable that is updated every 2 seconds with a new value ( speed ) , I want to keep saved the highest value .
How can I do?
snipper

```
var velocità = spazio / t1;    // km/h
         console.log('Stai andando a: ' + velocità);
         document.getElementById("velocità").innerHTML = velocità;
```

Comment: How is it updating? I mean where is the loop?

Comment: I question the need to put all the code , I just put the variable

Comment: @nonenane I'm having a hard time understanding what your question means... I mean, why is there an `Android` tag?

Comment: It's a android project with cordova

Comment: I just want to keep saved the highest value of the variable " velocità"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var max = 0;
...
...
if(velocità > max)
    max = velocità;
```

Comment: But save all values ​​or just the highest ?

Comment: This conditional will check if velocità when passed is the highest value. If it is the highest value, it will be saved under variable "max"

Comment: {   }; is not required ?

Comment: In JavaScript I'm not 100% sure, but in languages such as Java and C++ if there is only one line of code after the conditional curly brackets aren't mandatory.

Comment: I realized that when the variable speed is lowered , also the variable max is lowered . There not remains the highest value

Comment: If you're using the conditional it should definitely work if there is a loop where the code is. You need to make sure that var max is saved once the code is completed. This just saves the max value if it is continuously checked only in the function or wherever.

Comment: Ah, i dont save max...how i do ?

Comment: Personally I've never dealt with this problem, so you can ask others how to save data for whatever your project is, but I'd suggest using a database or even saving it into a file.